# preg_match_all in php produces different results with database string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, pcre

I am using preg_match_all in php to construct tokens from a string written in a DSL. When I hardcode a test string into my PHP code and run it, it all works. However, when I read the same string from a database it matches the first two tokens and then the rest of the string is matched as one token, when it clearly should be split into multiple sub units, as done when the string is hardcoded.

How can this be?

I am using .+ in my regular expression to match "the rest". Basically my DSL consists of keywords and the rest, so my regular expression for preg_match_all looks like this:

```
/(?P<NameOfKeyword1>Keyword1)|(?P<NameOfKeyword2>Keyword2)|(?P<NameOfKeyword3>Keyword3)|(?P<Linebreak>\\v+)|(?P<Rest>.+(?=Keyword1)|.+(?=Keyword2)|.+(?=Keyword3)|.+)/
```

Basically I first match keywords, then I match linebreaks, then the rest until the next keyword(or linebreak or end of string) appears.

So why does it match properly when the string is hardcoded but not when reading the same string from a database?

When reading from the database the rest of the string which is matched as one token, shouldn't be matched as one token, because it has keywords in between. It appears like it matches it based on .+

Edit:
The flags I use for preg_match_all are PREG_SET_ORDER and PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE

Comment: Maybe character encoding issues?

Comment: Possibly, how can I check this?

Comment: Read the string from the DB, then compare it to your hard-coded string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?P<Rest>.+(?=Keyword1)|.+(?=Keyword2)|.+(?=Keyword3)|.+)
```

This doesn't mean "*then the rest until the next keyword(or linebreak or end of string) appears.*". It will never stop except for new lines in fact.
Why? You're using lookaheads. Basically, `.(?=Keyword1)` means "any character followed by Keyword1" (with the `+` it just means "a sequence of characters, each followed by Keyword1").
So those won't scarcely match anything. The last `.+` is the reason the rest is matched entirely.

Now, if you make them [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), this should have the expected output:

```
(?P<Rest>.+?(?=Keyword1|Keyword2|Keyword3|$))
```

**Edit:**
Should also check for \v:

```
/(?P<NameOfKeyword1>Keyword1)
|(?P<NameOfKeyword2>Keyword2)
|(?P<NameOfKeyword3>Keyword3)
|(?P<Linebreak>\v+)
|(?P<Rest>.+?(?=Keyword1|Keyword2|Keyword3|\v|$))/
```

Comment: When I replace my regular expression with yours it no longer matches the rest. Only keywords and very few "rest".

Comment: Could you give an example? That'd be easier to test.

Comment: Here is an example string: http://pastebin.com/qS5Qaqhh It leaves out "Test Talk" but finds everything else. For a lot of other strings it works though.

Comment: @user975561 problem with the new lines. Editing this.